# The components of all linear combinations

Tags: linear-algebra

My linear Algebra homework has this question on it and I was wondering what the answer is.

The components of all linear combinations of v = (1, -2, 1) and w = (0, 1, -1) add up to _____

A simple google search came up with nothing so I thought I'd ask here.

If I had to guess I would say that they add up to 0 because by definition a linear combination is what you get when you resize any of the vectors by a skalar and add the two together, so I thought if you add all of linear combinations you'd get the span, and since the span is an infinite plane in all directions for these particular vectors, all numbers have a corresponding negative. So the sum would be 0.

Comment: More simple minded than that.  The components of $\bf v$ sum to $0$ the components of $\bf w$ sum to $0$ the components of any $a\mathbf v + b\mathbf w$ sum to...

Answer (score 1):

A linear combination has the form
$$
\alpha(1,-2,1)+\beta(0,1,-1)=
(\alpha,-2\alpha+\beta,\alpha-\beta)
$$
Then
$$
\alpha+(-2\alpha+\beta)+(\alpha-\beta)=0
$$

A nicer way to show this is to write vectors as columns and notice that a linear combination of the two vectors is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
-2 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha \\
\beta
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and that the sum of the components of the vector $v=\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{bmatrix}$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{bmatrix}
=v_1+v_2+v_3
$$
Since
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
-2 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
we also have
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
-2 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha \\
\beta
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha \\
\beta
\end{bmatrix}
=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\sum_{k=1}^3 [\alpha v + \beta w]_k = \alpha (\sum_{k=1}^3 [v]_k) + \beta (\sum_{k=1}^3 [w]_k) $.

Now compute $\sum_{k=1}^3 [v]_k = ?$ and $\sum_{k=1}^3 [w]_k = ?$.